# find first unique items selected by user and ranking them in order of user selection by date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, rank

I am trying to identify only first orders of unique "items" purchased by "test" customers in a simplified sample dataframe from the dataframe created below:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"cust": ['A55', 'A55', 'A55', 'B080', 'B080', 'D900', 'D900', 'D900', 'D900', 'C019', 'C019', 'Z09c', 'A987', 'A987', 'A987'],
    "date":['01/11/2016', '01/11/2016', '01/11/2016', '08/17/2016', '6/17/2016','03/01/2016',
           '04/30/2016', '05/16/2016','09/27/2016', '04/20/2016','04/29/2016', '07/07/2016', '1/29/2016', '10/17/2016', '11/11/2016' ],
    "item": ['A10BABA', 'A10BABA', 'A10DBDB', 'A9GABA', 'A11AD', 'G198A', 'G198A', 'F673', 'A11BB', 'CBA1', 'CBA1', 'DA21',
            'BG10A', 'CG10BA', 'BG10A']
})

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

df = df.sort_values(["cust", "date"], ascending = True)
```

The desired output would look as shown in picture - with all unique items ordered by date of purchase in a new column called "cust_item_rank" and remove any repeated (duplicated) orders of the same item by same user.

To clarify further, those items purchased on the same date by same user should have the same order/rank as shown in picture for customer A55 (A10BABA and A10DBDB are ranked as 1).
[image]

I have spent a fair bit of time using a combination of group by and/or rank operations but unsuccessful thus far. As an example:

```
df["cust_item_rank"] = df.groupby("cust")["date"]["item"].rank(ascending = 1, method = "min")
```

Yields an error (Exception: Column(s) date already selected).

Can somebody please guide me to the desired solution here?

Comment: I fail to understand, how is this different from a cumulative count? Also your sample DataFrame does not match the picture.

Comment: The dataframe includes duplicate orders of the same item(s) by some users.   The picture contains the final desired output without duplicate orders (i.e.,  only the items purchased by user and the order in which they were purchased).  Hence, this is not a cumulative count question.

Comment: Remove duplicates with `df = df[~df.groupby(['cust'])['item'].apply(pd.Series.duplicated)]` then your problem reduces to cumcount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this question, I built upon the excellent initial answer by cs95 and calling on the rank function in pandas as follows:

```
#remove duplicates as recommended by cs95
df2 = (df.loc[~df.groupby(['cust'])['item'].apply(pd.Series.duplicated)]
         .reset_index(drop=True))

#rank by date afer grouping by customer
df2["cust_item_rank"]= df2.groupby(["cust"])["date"].rank(ascending=1,method='dense').astype(int)
```

This resulted in the following (desired output):[image]

It appears that this problem is solved using either "min" or "dense" method of ranking but I chose the latter "dense" method to potentially avoid skipping any rank.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You can wait 2 days and then accept your own answer if you don't see anyone post anything better.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Remove duplicates
df2 = (df.loc[~df.groupby(['cust'])['item'].apply(pd.Series.duplicated)]
         .reset_index(drop=True))
df2['cust_item_rank'] = df2.groupby('cust').cumcount().add(1)
```

```
df2
    cust       date     item  cust_item_rank
0    A55 2016-01-11  A10BABA               1
1    A55 2016-11-01  A10DBDB               2
2   A987 2016-01-29    BG10A               1
3   A987 2016-10-17   CG10BA               2
4   B080 2016-06-17    A11AD               1
5   B080 2016-08-17   A9GABA               2
6   C019 2016-04-20     CBA1               1
7   D900 2016-03-01    G198A               1
8   D900 2016-05-16     F673               2
9   D900 2016-09-27    A11BB               3
10  Z09c 2016-07-07     DA21               1
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, please amend your question and/or data with a row that this solution will break on.

Comment: I amended the question to highlight a place where the solution isnt what I was hoping for. If a customer purchased two distinct items on same first visit, they should not be ranked 1 and 2 as is done with the current solution but have the same rank. Thus, I unaccepted your answer even though it was helpful - and will upvote it  instead.

Comment: I don't fully follow the pd.series_duplicated section of the code. For an alternative, replace the pd.series_duplicated section in code above with the following:                                    df2 = df.drop_duplicates(["cust","item"], keep = "first")